# How we can keep continue FileWatcher(java) on shared folders in Network interruption?

Tags: java, file, java-7, nio

I developed a `File Watcher` using `Watch Event` and `java.nio` for keeping watch on shared folder on LAN, but if network drops or interrupt, at that time watcher stoped. I removed break and create loop on `key.reset()` to wait until ping received again connection. By this watcher is remain continue... but after that it will not continue further.

Comment: Show us your watching code, please.

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) to help us better understand you problem. Have a look at this [link](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) also.

Comment: Oh man... edit your question an add the formatted code, please.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes the code is here, i m new on this block so problem with uploading the codes here